# Python “expected an indented block”

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling

I am running the following script for validation:

```
def num_val(x):
while True:
    try:
        userInput = raw_input("Please, enter the length of list " + x + " (only values from 1 to 100 are valid): ")
        val = int(userInput)
    except ValueError:
        print("Entered value must be a number. Please, write the number again")
        continue
    if userInput < 1 or userInput > 100:
        print ("Entered value must be a number in range from 1 to 100. Please write the number again")
    else:
break
num_val("a")
```

I receive following message:

```
print ("Entered value must be a number in range from 1 to 100. Please write the number again")
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Could you tell me what is the problem with that line?

Comment: Remove the space after the `print`

Comment: @Oisin I didn't have any problems with that - in py 2.7, `print` is a statement, so the `()` are no-ops around an expression consisting of a single string literal.

Comment: Your indentations are probably a mix of spaces and tabs like @cxw pointed out. Try using Sublime or any other editor to pull back the indentation (Shift+Tab) and then reindent using Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a copy and paste, it looks like your code may have a mix of spaces and tabs, which can cause strange errors.  The below works for me:

```
def num_val(x):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = raw_input("Please, enter the length of list " + x + " (only values from 1 to 100 are valid): ")
            val = int(userInput)
        except ValueError:
            print("Entered value must be a number. Please, write the number again")
            continue
        if val < 1 or val > 100:    # <-- use "val" instead of "userInput"
            print ("Entered value must be a number in range from 1 to 100. Please write the number again")
        else:
            break

num_val("a")
```

How to prevent these sorts of problems?  Depends on your editor.  Many editors have a setting to "expand tabs" or some such, and for Python code you should take advantage of that feature.  That way, when you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the editor will insert spaces.  In Python, [<kbd>Tab</kbd> characters line up every 8 columns](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation), and spaces at other indentations may confuse the parser.

Also note that the `if` statement should use `val` instead of `userInput`, since `val` is the number and `userInput` is the text.

Comment: After deleting spaces manually and adding tabs, the problem is solved.